# Banner in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, banner

I had created content type then view and display it as a block. Then enable the block. Banner images are showing but javascript of my banner is not applying? as i uncluded it in .info file also?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make an image carousel or slider?

You may want to checkout [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow).

If you added the js file to the info file of your theme, you might need to flush the cache for it show up.

After that, you'd need to have specific js to target the images within the view.

Comment: Thanku for your reply jason, I was doing a silly mistake